# change user in sudo bash script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sudo

In a bash script that is called with sudo i am calling:

/usr/bin/firefox -new-tab http://stackoverflow.com

but then i get the message:

> Firefox is already running, but is not
>   responding. To open a new window, you
>   must first close the existing Firefox
>   process, or restart your system

this is, i guess, because the script is called by sudo and firefox by the normal user.
if i would call the command without sudo it works.

so how can i switch back to the normal user in a sudo called script?

Comment: The su(1) command is used to change user id. I recall that Ubuntu makes it difficult to use, but most other systems include and support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using sudo again inside your script.

```
sudo -u user -H /usr/bin/firefox -new-tab http://stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://calum.org/posts/running-firefox-as-another-user-using-sudo) might answer your question

Comment: wow, i was actually thinking about something that can be done in the script itself, any chance?